# How can I optimize my random value generation?

Tags: r

I was given a probability distribution that I cannot find in any R packages, and I was told to generate random values from it. The probability distribution function is called the LogGamma distribution and has the following probability distribution function.

[; f(x) = \frac{\alpha^\beta}{\Gamma(\beta)}(\ln{x})^{\beta-1}x^{-\alpha-1} ;]

Because I can't find an explicit expression for the inverse of the integral of this expression, I created a function that iterates through a series of values until it arrives at the stopping point that returns the desired probability.

```
LogGammaPDF <- function(x){
      return(alpha^beta * log(x)^(beta - 1) * x^(-alpha-1)/gamma(beta))
      }

MakeLogGammaRV <- function(n){
      LogGammaRandomValues = c()
      for(j in seq(1:n)){
        i = 1
        Prob = runif(1)
        while(integrate(LogGammaPDF, lower=1, upper=i)$value < Prob){
          i = i + .0001
        }
        LogGammaRandomValues[j] = i
      }
}

MakeLogGammaRV(10)
```

Making 10 random variables takes about a minute. How can I optimize this process?

---

You'll need [TeX the World](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tex-the-world-for-chromiu/mbfninnbhfepghkkcgdnmfmhhbjmhggn) to see my equation.

Comment: This page (https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html) has a listing of possible packages for the log-gamma

Comment: Also, the second answer on this question (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow) provides a better alternative for LaTeX on Stack Overflow - in case you need to post a formula in the future :)

Comment: To generate values from an arbitrary distribution, you can invert the CDF for that distribution and feed random Uniform(0, 1) values into it: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling . Useful when the distribution isn't available in any packages.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it matches your definition or not, but `library("sos"); findFn("log-gamma")` finds `?VGAM::rlgamma`, which is:

```
function (n, location = 0, scale = 1, shape = 1) 
{
    ans <- location + scale * log(rgamma(n, shape))
    ans[scale < 0] <- NaN
    ans
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something. According to [this](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/GammaLoggamma.pdf) the natural log of a gamma random variable follows a log-gamma distribution (which makes sense given the name). Furthermore, the R function `rgamma()` returns gamma-random variables. Thus you could use e.g. `log(rgamma(10,alpha,beta))` to get what you want.

If this doesn't work, the package [VGAM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VGAM/index.html) has an `rlgamma()` function.

Comment: this basically describes what VGAM::rlgamma does, with the addition of a location parameter

Comment: @BenBolker Good to know. I haven't had occasion to use this distribution and was somewhat confused by the way in which a Google search seemed to turn up a couple of subtly different distributions which go by the name of `log-gamma`

Comment: @JohnColeman "a Google search seemed to turn up a couple of subtly different distributions which go by the name of log-gamma" - That was my problem!